# Problema al leer un valor numérico de un excel

Tags: java, excel

Mi problema es que tengo un excel en el cual una de las columnas tiene un formato numérico (el cual no puedo cambiar) y al leerlo desde java me lee todo el valor con comas. Por ejemplo si yo en mi excel relleno una celda de esa columna con el valor **3123456,89**, el excel lo muestra como **3.123.456,89** pero java lo lee y me lo muestra como **3,123,456,89**.

Cuando intento pasar el valor de esa celda a Double, no me sale el valor correcto. La manera en la que leo el valor de la celda es la siguiente:

```
cell = row.getCell(cont);
stringValue = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
```

Comment: No recuerdo bien métodos de Java pero te digo lo que haría.
Elimina las comas o puntos con algun metodo tipo replace de la clase String. Seguro que habrá alguna. Después de eliminar los puntos, convierte la variable de String a Long y ya.

Comment: @Lorthas pero si elimino los puntos y las comas mi número 3123456.89. al pasarlo a String y luego a Long se convertiría en 312345689, eliminaría el decimal

Comment: Tienes razón. No me había fijado en eso.
Que librería usas para coger datos de un excel con Java?